# compiler-optimization for numerical stability

Tags: compiler-optimization, numerical

do GCC or similar compilers perform optimizations that are aimed at improving the numerical stability of floating-point operations.

It is known that seemingly simply operations like addition or computing the norm of a vector are numerically unstable if implemented in the obvious manner, and, on the other hand, compilers sometimes destroy work-arounds for these problems for the sake of speed optimization.

What is the state of the art of optimizing compiler output for numerical stable computation? Anything better than pending?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle (formerly Sun) compilers for Linux and Solaris.
Their C++ and Fortran compilers have support for [Interval Arithmetics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3696/)